# Building only ROS messages or services

Tags: ros, build, rosmake, services, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to only build ROS message or services without building the entire package?  I sometimes want to separate the building of the entire package and just the messages to more concisely determine if I have an issue.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45916/building-only-ros-messages-or-services/) by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on ROS Answers with karma: 506 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, people just create a package that does not contain anything but messages to split up the dependency tree and to not force the user to compile source code if she just wants messages. You can find many examples for this in ROS, for instance [nav_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/nav_msgs), [geometry_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/geometry_msgs), [std_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/std_msgs), etc.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-15**:
+1 A separate message and service package is a best-practice that almost everyone should follow.